# Flutter how to save array in class and print in any page

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to save an array globally so I can use on every page. So I just create a model class like this

```
class wishList {
  var wishlistArray = [];
}
```

What I need to do is just put values in wishListArray.

I am adding like this

```
wishList.wishlistArray.add(product['ID']);
```

It's showing this error `Instance member 'wishlistArray' can't be accessed using static access.`

What I need to is now just save values in an array and print that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the `wishlistArray`, a `static` variable.

```
 class WishList {
    static var wishlistArray = [];
 }

 WishList.wishlistArray.add();
```

or create an instance of `WishList` when calling the array

```
WishList().wishlistArray.add();
```

or make `WishList` a `Singleton` class

```
class WishList {
   var wishlistArray = [];
   
   WishList._privateConstructor();
   
   static final WishList instance = WishList._privateConstructor();   
   
 }
```

Then you can use it like this :

```
WishList.instance.wishlistArray.add();
```

Answer (score 1):

You try access no static member of class.

You meant this?:

```
class AppConfig {
  static final wishlistArray = new List<String>();
}

void main() {
  AppConfig.wishlistArray.add('Hi');
  AppConfig.wishlistArray.add('Man');
  print(AppConfig.wishlistArray);
}
```

And global List variable it does not have to be inside the class. Use only:

```
final wishlistArrayGlb = new List<String>();

void main() { 
  wishlistArrayGlb.add('Hi Global');
  wishlistArrayGlb.add('Man Global');
  print(wishlistArrayGlb);
}
```

Comment: `new List<String>()` is deprecated because it's not compatible with null safety by default (NNBD).